# unable to process "tikz" package

Tags: tikz-pgf

I kept getting this message but I do not know how to fix this:

`(pgfutil-common.tex) (pgfutil-latex.def
! Undefined control sequence.
l.13 \pgfutil@format@is@latextrue`

It must be due to the setting, because the same LaTeX file works on my other computer in my office.

Please help! Thank you!

Comment: Sadly, you have provided virtually no information whereby help is likely to be available. Please edit your question to include a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)). Otherwise the advice will be: 'you need to define the control sequence'....

Answer (score 2):

```
(pgfutil-common.tex) (pgfutil-latex.def
```

Usually TeX also reports the directories of the included files. Thus, these files are in the current working directory, why?

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.13 \pgfutil@format@is@latextrue
```

`pgfutil-common.tex` should contain:

```
\newif\ifpgfutil@format@is@latex
```

Therefore, my assumption is, that the current directory is cluttered with files of different `pgf` versions. TikZ/`pgf` should be installed as part of the TeX distribution. Then, start in a fresh directory with the TeX file only and try again. The screen output/`.log` file should then show the correct locations of the `pgf` files and this error should be gone.